# ng-switch not reacting to dynamic value change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am new and experimenting with AngularJS.

That being said, i am unsure how to bind value to an ng-switch and change between views dynamically by changing the 'activeView' variable value.

Side note: is it a good practice to switch between views like this? The views are different ways of displaying the same data so its pretty much the same context and i did not see a reason to create a different page for the two views. Oh and the views contents are actually directives components.

the html:

```
<body ng-controller="SomeController as vm">
    <div ng-switch="{{vm.activeView}}">
        <div ng-switch-when="someView">
            some directive component
        </div>

        <div ng-switch-when="anotherView">
            another directive component
        </div>

        <div ng-switch-default>
            nothing to show
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

the controller:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('SomeController', SomeController);

function SomeController() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.activeView = '';

    function setViewType(viewType) {
        vm.viewTypes = viewType;
    }

    setViewType('anotherView');
}
})();
```

So what happen is that the default switch is visible, event after calling setViewType('anotherView');

Thanks in advance!

Comment: loose the {{}} you don't need to interpolate
`ng-switch="vm.activeView"`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however it did not fix the problem. :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't need the interpolation when using ng-switch ({{vm.activeView}}).
2. You aren't assigning vm.activeView with a value.
3. Your angular.module doesn't have a dependency array. If this is the place that you define your module then add it.

   ```
   (function () {
   'use strict';

   angular.module('app', []) // add the dependency array
       .controller('SomeController', SomeController);

   function SomeController() {
       var vm = this;

       vm.activeView = 'anotherView'; // change this

       function setViewType(viewType) {
           vm.viewTypes = viewType;
       }

       setViewType('anotherView'); // this changes the viewTypes prop
   }
   })();
   ```

Check on this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/x4835y4d/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually the angular module is defined elsewhere like so 'angular.module('app', []);', also you are right, i dont set any default value, this is because i want the value to change on a click of button, let say i click a button and it calls setViewType('someView') then i want the activeView value to change and the html to display the view in the switch based on that dynamic value.

Comment: @SlashJ - setViewType updates the viewTypes prop and the the activeView prop. I set a hard coded value just for convenience. This will work with a dynamic assignment as well.